# nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

Tags: spring-integration

I am new to spring-integration, when i execute my simple program in eclipse(mars), I am getting error below. Kindly help me to resolve on this.

> nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 18;
>   columnNumber: 58; cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'channel' must appear
>   on element 'int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter'

Answer (score 0):

Please, take a look here [Eclipse gradle project's spring xml validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20656424/eclipse-gradle-projects-spring-xml-validation/20657440#20657440).

And share the config, of course, if you are not sure in it.