# cvc-complex-type Eclipse XML error for every Spring-Integration element

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, spring, spring-integration

Suddenly I got 100 Eclipse errors like this:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type

cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter'.    cache-config.xml    /smartdestinations-sf/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/conf/spring/integration   line 34 XML Problem

Actually, I am getting this error for every spring-integration element.
Is there any possibility to fix?

The beginning of the XML file is as follows, the particular error is related to the 1st element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:int-amqp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp/spring-integration-amqp-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.smartdestinations.sfweb.service.cache" />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:module.properties" ignore-unresolvable="false" />
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter id="cacheInboundChannelAdaptor" auto-startup="${cache.processing.enabled}"
    channel="cacheRoutingChannel" 
    queue-names="${cache.queue.name}" 
    header-mapper="cacheMessageHeaderMapper"
    connection-factory="connectionFactory" 
    error-channel="cacheErrorChannel" />
```

I am also getting errors for Spring xsd files:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type

Referenced file contains errors (http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd).  For more information, right click on the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details..." inventory-config.xml    /smartdestinations-sf/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/conf/spring/inventory line 1  XML Problem

Show details contains the message: "A schema cannot contain two global elements with the same name, this schema contains two occurrences   of 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans, identified type'.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20656424/eclipse-gradle-projects-spring-xml-validation/20657440#20657440